Windows 11 changes volume when running through receiver and turning the TV off
I have only 1 sound device in windows 11 sound devices "insignia-TV"
It is connected through a Yamaha RX-V479 receiver
when I lower the volume and turn the TV off, the sound stays on, as I want it.
But around 5 minutes later, the sound goes to full volume
I dont know why this is happening.
This seems to be a windows 11 problem, not the receiver. The receiver voluem remains unchanged

This might be caused by a feature similar to the "HDMI Standby" option in my Yamaha RX-V465. If I recall correctly, during normal usage, the receiver exposes the TV to the PC over the HDMI connection, but during low-power operation (like when the receiver is in standby or the TV is off), the PC instead sees a different HDMI output device that represents the receiver instead of the TV. Windows has separate volume levels for each audio output device, so changing the device like this can result in volume changes.
It's not exactly the same cause as what you described, but the symptoms of exposing different HDMI output devices to the PC depending on power states makes me think it's related.
You could try

disabling this feature if you have it. On my receiver it's under Setup > HDMI > Standby. There may be other power saving options in the receiver that you can modify too.
always leaving the Windows audio output level at 100% for all devices, and only using the receiver to change volume.
manually reducing the volume in Windows after it goes to 100%, which should at least be persisted whenever that device is used in the future.
temporarily connecting another monitor to your PC, or using a remote connection like VNC, so that you can examine the audio devices and volume levels when this issue occurs. This is how I noticed that a different audio device appeared in mmsys.cpl when I turned off my TV, because the device name changed from Samsung to Yamaha.

I had a similar problem with a Marantz receiver where the audio devices would similarly change maybe 30 minutes after turning off the TV, except in my case it would stop playback entirely with some horrible DirectSound error message because of an issue with the changeover between the two audio devices, instead of resuming playback at the wrong volume. I worked around this by sending audio to the receiver through a separate optical audio cable using a USB audio interface, and configuring the receiver to use that optical audio in for my PC's input instead of HDMI audio. Since the USB audio interface isn't affected by the TV turning off, it keeps playing the same forever, without any quirks from power states or device changes.
